# Need help,writing a python BMI calc

Tags: python

I am new to python and and currently learning to use functions properly.

```
h = 1.75
w = 70.5
bmi = float(w / h ** 2)


if bmi < 18.5:
    print('过轻')
elif 18.5 <= bmi < 25:
    print('正常')
elif 25 <= bmi < 28:
    print('过重')
elif 28 <= bmi < 32:
    print('肥胖')
else bmi >= 32:
    print('严重肥胖')
```

Every time I run this program as an attempt I come into this error

```
File "/Users/frank/Coding/bmimyself.py", line 17
    else bmi >= 32:
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I would appreciate any assistance with my coding errors I must have made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't apply a condition like `bmi >= 32` in an `else` statement.  An `else` statement handles the case when none of the previous if/elif statements were True, so it's already associated with an implicit condition.

You should have:

```
if bmi < 18.5:
    print('过轻')
elif 18.5 <= bmi < 25:
    print('正常')
elif 25 <= bmi < 28:
    print('过重')
elif 28 <= bmi < 32:
    print('肥胖')
else:
    print('严重肥胖')
```

To avoid the SyntaxError.

Answer (score 0):

This statement is not "else", it is another "elif".

```
elif bmi >= 32:
  print 'foo'
else:
  print 'bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
elif bmi >= 32:
```

with just "else" you cannot have conditional expression. It instead means if none of the condition above satisfied then do this.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply change the last "**else**" to "**elif**"

**else** statement is something like last resort option if none of the above **elif** conditions are met.